# Internal working of Cassandra during SELECT query

Tags: select, cassandra

How does Cassandra internally work when there is a query like

`select <column> from <table>`

Does it pick the whole row and then filter the required column to be put in the resultSet. Or does it directly pick only the requested column?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6588... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10657

Comment: Basically cassandra 3.4 fetches only columns selected... earlier version used to fetch complete row and filter